# MAMP VirtualHost chooses wrong directory

Tags: apache, mamp, vhosts, hosts

I got a problem with MAMP.

I added in the httpd-vhosts.conf these lines of code:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName "site1.dev"
    DocumentRoot "/Users/kevingorjan/site1/public_html/"

    <Directory "/Users/kevingorjan/site1/public_html/">
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName "site2.dev"
    DocumentRoot "/Users/kevingorjan/site2/public_html/"

    <Directory "/Users/kevingorjan/site2/public_html/">
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

And I updated my /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1 site1.dev
127.0.0.1 site2.dev
```

When I surf to site1.dev. Everything goes as expected. The servers loads the correct content specified to this URL. But when I surf to site2.dev, I'll receive the same content from site1.dev. Is there something that I miss or do I have to change something else in the configuration?

Thanks in advance

*** SOLUTION ***

**Sorry, I found the problem.
I'm working on my Mac and I have apache running while my MAMP is also running. I removed the apache on my machine and now everything is working fine.
Thanks**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I found the problem.

I'm working on my Mac and I have apache running while my MAMP is also running.
I removed the apache on my machine and now everything is working fine.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You're doing it wrong ;) Your virtualhosts file should look more like this :

```
NameVirtualHost *:80 

<Directory "D:/projects/">
  Require local
</Directory> 

<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot "D:/projects/project_1/public_html"
 ServerName project_1.dev
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot "D:/projects/project_2/public_html"
 ServerName project_2.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

IF you are using apache < 2.4 than replace :

```
Require local
```

with :

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

Answer (score -1):

In your hosts file make sure you supply the ipv6 address for your site along with the ipv4

```
127.0.0.1 site1.dev
127.0.0.1 site2.dev
::1 site1.dev
::1 site2.dev
```

You might not need the directory tag in your vhosts.conf file

Also make sure that MAMP is using MySQL and Apache default ports and not MAMP defaults in the preferences pane.