# Virtualhost in MAMP (not MAMP pro) is linking to wrong file directory

Tags: apache, mamp, vhosts

Before I go ahead I want to note that I have the same problem as the person who posted this question, but in my instance the solution here did not fix my problem: [MAMP VirtualHost chooses wrong directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17322422/mamp-virtualhost-chooses-wrong-directory)

Also, in my instance the code is slightly different.

**The second VirtualHost (dev.motorbikewebsite), for whatever reason, is linking to the DocumentRoot for the first VirtualHost (dev.phpcourse), despite having it's own DocumentRoot.**

"Hosts" file:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0     localhost
127.0.0.1       dev.motorbikewebsite
127.0.0.1       dev.phpcourse
```

"httpd-vhosts.conf" file:

```
NameVirtualHost *:8888

<Directory "/Users/oliverdenny/Dekstop/">
  Require local
</Directory>


<VirtualHost *:8888>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/oliverdenny/Desktop/phpcourse"
    ServerName phpcourse
        ServerAlias dev.phpcourse
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:8888>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/oliverdenny/Desktop/motorbikewebsite"
    ServerName motorbikewebsite
        ServerAlias dev.motorbikewebsite
</VirtualHost>
```

In both of the source folders/document roots, there is an "index.php" file; both share the same name but are different files and have different content. I've tried resolving the issue by both changing the types of files (.html) and the names of the files...but to no avail.

Other than this issue, there don't appear to be any other problems.

I feel like I've tried all the solutions which are potentially low-hanging fruit, but nevertheless there's probably something obvious which I'm still missing here!

Any ideas?

Other notes:
 *macOS Catalina v10.15.3 
 *MAMP v5.6 
 *Apache Port: 8888 
 *Nginx Port: 7888 
 *MySQLPort: 8889